# Как получить основную информацию из аудиофайла в python?

Tags: python-3.x

Есть некий аудиофайл, в нем есть данные о картинке, о названии песни и автора, о продолжительности аудиофайла и т.д. Эти данные можно получить зайдя в свойства самого файла в винде. А как можно эти данные получить в python и в дальнейшем использовать?

Я про них:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/102285/10090254

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека [eyeD3](https://pypi.org/project/eyeD3/) для работы с аудиофайлами. [Документация](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) к ней.

Если коротко, то:

```
import eyeD3

tag = eyeD3.Tag()
tag.link('/file.mp3')

print (tag.getArtist())
print (tag.getAlbum())
print (tag.getTitle())
```

Comment: А можно конкретный пример с извлечением картинки из аудиофайла. А то я чет не нашел такого.